# List operations on own types consisting of one list

Tags: haskell, ghci

I got the type "`Signal`" that is only a list of doubles and I want to use normal list-operations like on a native `[Double]`. This should be possible but it just won't compile. How would you describe this to the compiler syntactically correct.

Here is the test code:

```
data Signal = Signal [Double] deriving(Show, Eq)

test :: Signal
test = Signal [1.0,2.0,3.0]

take2 :: Signal -> Signal
take2 s = take 2 s
```

Expected: `take2 test = [1.0,2.0]`

Actual:

```
"Couldn't match expected type ‘Signal’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
In the expression: take 2 s
In an equation for ‘take2’: take2 s = take 2 s"
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that the function definition as below:

```
take2 :: Signal -> Signal
take2 s = take 2 s
```

`s` is not a list, it is a `Signal` and `take 2 s` is a list, not a `Signal`, The thing you need is get the list from `Signal` and construct a `Signal` from a list as:

```
take2 (Signal s) = Signal $ take 2 s
```

Comment: Also, consider using `newtype Signal = Signal [Double]` instead of `data ...` so that the compiler knows it can dispense with the wrapper in the run-time representation.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing which analogies to use, I'll assume a C/++/#/etc background -

```
data Signal = Signal [Double]
```

Is equivalent to

```
struct Signal { vector<double> contents; };
```

If you wish is to actually represent a `[Double]` directly rather than containing it, i.e something akin to

```
typedef vector<double> Signal;
```

Then that's called a "type synonym" in Haskell and defined using:

```
type Signal = [Double]
```